# Where are directshow media types documented?

Tags: directshow

MSDN documents type and sub types GUIDs but not the actual byte format of media sample payloads.  Some types are defined in other standards, such as MPEG2 types.  For most types, you have to guess and test.  Is there a header in the Windows SDK with the definitions?

Comment: Media types hardly exist all in single place - there is a variety of them and you can use custom ones too.

Comment: Maybe the [fourcc Web site](http://www.fourcc.org/) might help you.

Comment: @StevensMiller Thanks, that's useful.  Many GUIDs are derived from fourcc.

Comment: Glad to help. Hang onto to your hat, though: there's truly no end to the search for format info, because part of the great virtue of things like DirectShow is that they can handle _anything_ as the payload. You could even (though, please, don't) define your own format. In practice, you will probably end up seeing the same formats over and over. But there is no one place anyone can go to find a description of every format that might ever exist. You just have to cope with them as they come along.